# How can I turn off the "low battery" noise?

Tags: notifications, battery, samsung-vibrant

I've started getting a loud beep notification when my battery hits 15%.  Possibly this happened after an [Audio Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartandroidapps.audiowidget) update but I don't see any settings in the app to change it.  Previously the notification was silent, I didn't even know it could have a sound!  There doesn't seem to be a relevant setting under `Settings -> Sound`.

How can I disable this notification sound?

I'm rooted, running 2.2 (TeamWhiskey's NextGen v1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into `/system/media/audio/ui`, you can delete/rename `LowBattery.ogg` to remove the low battery sound. This will work as long as it is using the system low battery sound as an alert. I don't know anything about Audio Manager, or whether this is even possible, but it may be using its own sound, in which case this would not work.

This requires:

1. A rooted device
2. A SuperUser enabled file browser/terminal emulator
3. /system to be mounted in read/write mode

Comment: For the rest of us reading this, this requires root.