# How can I disable the low-battery sound in Cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, audio, alerts, mute

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S3 running Cyanogenmod 11 (20140804-SNAPSHOT-M9-i9300). When the battery hits ~15% or 5%, an alert appears with a warning sound. How can I disable this warning sound (without removing the popup alert)?

I've tried [removing](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/29869/32143) `/system/media/audio/ui/LowBattery.ogg`; this did not prevent an alert sound, but the sound did change, perhaps to a fallback. I also tried installing "[Suppress Low Battery Sound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsideout.silentbattery)" (aka "Disable Low Battery Beep" via the web browser), but this had no effect either. I tried installing [Sound Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgg.soundmanager&hl=en), and turning the system sound down, but this also had no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [advice](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/80891/how-can-i-disable-the-low-battery-sound-in-cyanogenmod/80897?noredirect=1#comment103504_80897) from Narayanan, I replaced `/system/media/audio/ui/LowBattery.ogg` with another `.ogg` file. The next time it was triggered, the new file played.

I then tried placing an empty file at `/system/media/audio/ui/LowBattery.ogg`, but this did not work.

Finally, I downloaded a slient `.ogg` from [here](http://blog.ginzburgconsulting.com/silencing-the-battery-charging-completed-sound-on-a-samsung-galaxy-sii/), placing it at `/system/media/audio/ui/LowBattery.ogg`. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I see Sparhawk wants to disable the warning sound alone and not the popup. I stumbled on an xposed module which will disable both. I just keep this posted just in case if Sparhawk wants to slightly compromise on the requirement and also probably will help others who read this post.

Text from the post:

> **Disable the Low Battery Alert with Xposed** *POSTED OCTOBER 13, 2013 AT
> 12:30 AM BY WILL VERDUZCODIFFICULTY:1*
>
> Disable the Low Battery Alert
> with Xposed There are plenty of Xposed modules out there. Their
> purposes range widely from adding previously device-specific
> functionality to patching bugs, and everything in between. This is, of
> course, all made possible by XDA Recognized Developer rovo89‘s
> fantastic Xposed Framework (thread) . The framework allows developers
> to create a module APK that is able to make a modification at runtime,
> while leaving original files intact. Both a boost in ease-of-use and
> user safety, Xposed makes device modification into a click and reboot
> affair.
>
> A new Xposed module from XDA Senior Member defim has appeared, and its
> purpose is to remove that annoying low battery popup alert that you
> are given when running low on juice. Yes, being notified that your
> battery is running low is generally useful. However, for those of us
> who actively look at the battery meter in our status bars, it’s a bit
> redundant. Furthermore, if you happen to be in a call when you receive
> this alert, it will generally turn on your screen, thus reactivating
> the touch sensor. For yours truly, this has resulted in accidentally
> ended phone calls, unintentional muting, and more.
>
> The module will work on any ICS+ device with Xposed Framework
> installed. Simply install the module, activate it, and reboot. To tame
> your low battery alert, head over to the module thread.

The exposed module is available [in this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-hidebatterylowalert-t2480714).

**Update:**
I happen to notice that with [GravityBox](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v3-1-4-tweak-box-android-t2316070) You get an option to disable sound alone. The screenshot of that option is as below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did come across this in my searches, but as you acknowledge, it doesn't exactly solve my problem. I do like the popup, just not the sound. In fact, if forced to make a choice, I'd prefer to keep both rather than lose both. Cheers anyway.

Comment: Your advice in the comments of the other answer led me to the [solution](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/81170/32143). I started editing the information into this answer, so that I could accept it, but I thought that such a large edit would be rejected. Perhaps you want to edit my answer in, or copy-paste into a new one so I can accept and upvote? Cheers.

Comment: GravityBox is not recommended with Cyanogenmod because of the heavy customization of the latter.

Answer (score -3):

Well, I am not going to take credit of this answer, I just googled out the answer of this question.

Head over to the /system/media/audio/ui it will have LowBattery.ogg file rename it to something different like LowBattery.ogg.bak or something else. It will not bother you.

PS: You need to be a rooted user to do that and yes removing the LowBattery.ogg try renaming and let me know about it !

Comment: How does renaming it differ from removing it? They are essentially the same. In any case, I "removed" it by moving it to another location, which is equivalent to renaming it in Linux terms.

Comment: Well, at least I think you can give it a try ! Who know if it may solve your issue !

Comment: I am just wondering why sound is heard even when the OGG file is removed. My guess is probably it fall back to some other file or a hard coded value. Instead of removing try replacing it with a known sound file. If this works, you can generate an OGG file with silence and replace.

Comment: @PeterCarlos Well, perhaps post up your reference at least. Also, I'm quite familiar with Linux, and I cannot imagine how this could work. Perhaps the inode of the file would be consistent, if it were moved in a particular way, but even then, I cannot imagine how this would be relevant, since we want the absence of a file, not the presence.

Comment: @Narayanan I think your guess might be correct, although it's a very strange way to code it. I double-checked the file I moved, and it's the same sound. I tried putting in a different sound, and we'll see what happens. Another possibility is that it's cached somewhere, and I need to delete this file, or refresh the cache.

Comment: @Sparhawk In that case I can't comment more over it as it looks like I just ran out of options. I would say maybe you should wait a bit more while and see if someone else over the community can come up with some new ideas.